# Why am I unable to intercept 401 and handle session expired on AJAX call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, devise

I'm currently working on legacy software and running into an issue. When a session is expired and a formtastic form is submitted it attempts to go to inspections#create is returned with a 401 and attempts to render inspections#index. The problem is inspections#index doesn't exist. When the session expires in all other cases it redirects to the sign in page. My assumption is that without the parameters from the form it is misinterpreting the route to just '/inspections/'. This seems to be a problem with AJAX calls after a session has expired when using Devise.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry one more request - can you post your controllers/application.rb? (possibly in a /api/ folder)

It doesn't look like it's actually reacting InspectionController#create - it's just calling the Devise wrapper which is probably in application.rb (or at least referenced there).

It looks like your authentication model not only checks the user, but it also checks the Customer, Version, and Event. One of those is causing your Devise wrapper to return unauthorized. When it does that, it's calling the undefined index action (doesn't appear to be redirecting, just rendering).

If I can see the authentication wrapper for the controller, I'll be able to provide more

(Sorry this isn't an answer but I can't comment until my reputation is up)

Comment: I posted both the application.rb and application_controller just to be safe. I appreciate all the help. With the new information you've already provided, I'm able to see certain things more clearly.

Comment: I've also added the only class I could find that inherits from DeiveController.

Answer (score 1):

If you can debug, you'll want to add a breakpoint here:

```rb
  unless Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local

    rescue_from Exception, with: lambda { |exception|
      if exception.class == CanCan::AccessDenied
        redirect_to root_path, notice: exception.to_s
      else
        Airbrake.notify(exception); render_error 500, exception
      end
    }
    rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, ActionController::UnknownController, ::AbstractController::ActionNotFound, ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: lambda { |exception| Airbrake.notify(exception); render_error 404, exception }
  end
```

I think the create action is unauthorized to the user, so it's trying to redirect to `root_path`, but `root_path` (index) is undefined, so you're 1) it's reaching the code `redirect_to root_path, notice: exception.to_s` but on the second request 2) it's reaching this code: `rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, ActionController::UnknownController, ::AbstractController::ActionNotFound, ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: lambda { |exception| Airbrake.notify(exception); render_error 404, exception }`

It could be due to the scope: root_path on one controller might be valid because index is defined, but on another it's undefined. I'd say check your other controllers for example index actions to see how they are handling it.

Let me know what you find :)

Comment: Unfortunately, that block is never executed in this case.

Comment: I did notice that once I create an inspections#index, after the session is expired and I submit the form, it redirects to the login page.

Comment: @asnyder002 Do you have access to the AirBrake UI? https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake shows a UI that would give you a stack trace.

It still looks to me like it called that line of code... this makes sense based on your last comment because adding the triggers a second root_path redirection. Can you post the logs from when you have an index action enabled?

Ideally AirBrake will give you more useful information with where the exception is being throw.

Comment: I do have access to AirBrake but the stack trace is so generic 
"/gems/actionpack-3.2.22.5/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:116 in process
/gems/actionpack-3.2.22.5/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:46 in process"

I put a breakpoint in that block of code and never gets called but I see where you're coming from. You were correct in that inspections#create never actually gets called. Inpsections#index never actually gets called either. The view doesn't exist but once it hits that endpoint it redirects to sign in properly. There is some processes happening prior to the path.

Comment: Do you have another application.rb? I see from the routes.rb there are 2 versions of the API, so you may have app/api/v1 and app/api/v2 with application.rb.